# Ruta no encontrada en mi @Html.Action

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tengo un action child, que uso para poder invocar una vista en un layout, pero al momento de usar el *@HTML.Action*, me marca que el controlador que le paso no ha sido encontrado.

```
 <li class="dropdown">

                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu alert-dropdown">
                            @Html.Action("Not", "EntrevistaIdiomaController");
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Mi action result child

```
     [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Not()
    {
        return PartialView("_Notificacion", m_entrevistaIdiomaDAO.TodosXFecha());
    }
```

El error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Verificar que su controlador implemente `IController` , es decir debe ser `public class EntrevistaIdiomaController : Controller { ..}` , podría añadir el código de su controlador?

Comment: Si lo implementa, esta tal cual lo pusiste.

Comment: ¿Has intentado ponerlo sin el sufijo `Controller`, o sea, `@Html.Action("Not", "EntrevistaIdioma");`?

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos! <3 , este error me costo dos dias de trabajo, ambas soluciones funcionaron, solo que habia que quitarle el sufijo Controller.

Comment: Si te sirvió, voy a ponerlo como respuesta a tu pregunta; no olvides marcar la respuesta como la solución para que, en el futuro, quien tenga el mismo problema sepa que hay una solución :D

Answer (score 1):

Intenta hacerlo igual **pero** sin el sufijo `Controller`, así:

```
@Html.Action("Not", "EntrevistaIdioma");
```

Usualmente, cuando llamas a un controlador lo vas a hacer así, el armado de MVC te ahorra tener que llamar a la clase por nombre completo :)